# UFT doesnt get milliseconds from SQL

Tags: sql, vbscript, qtp

Trying to get time from MS SQL. The time format in database is `MM/DD/YYY hh:mm:ss.mls`.
When reading via UFT, it gets the time without milliseconds but rounds seconds by milliseconds, i.e. if it is `1:48:33.724`, UFT gives `1:48:34` and if it is `1:48:33.245` UFT gives `1:48:33`.
How to avoid that rounding and get full time format?

Comment: How are you getting this value from SQL? You could modify your query to return time with milliseconds.

Comment: `SELECT p.Name, P.Description,p.Share, e.Name, p.OpenSDate, p.OpenEDate, p.EffectiveDate, p.CreatedBy, p.CreateDate, p.DeativedBy, p.DeactiveDate FROM [tblProgram] p inner  join [tblMapping] pm on p.ProgramID = pm.ProgramID inner join [tblEntity] e on pm.EntityID = e.EntityID order by 1,4"'
----
In MS SQL, this query gives time with milliseconds in table. But in UFT I have not the milliseconds ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I had to modify my query to return the milliseconds. I modified to this:

```
SELECT p.Name, P.Description,p.Share, e.Name, p.OpenSDate, p.OpenEDate, p.EffectiveDate, p.CreatedBy, CAST(p.CreateDate AS datetime2(3)) AS 'CreateDate', p.DeativedBy, CAST(p.DeactiveDate AS datetime2(3)) AS 'DeactiveDate' FROM [tblProgram] p inner join [tblMapping] pm on p.ProgramID = pm.ProgramID inner join [tblEntity] e on pm.EntityID = e.EntityID order by 1,4
```

Originally, database had 3 numbers for milliseconds, so I used datetime2(3). In UFT I just splitted it:

```
dbDate = CDate(Split(dbCellData, ChrW(32))(0)) 'this gives the date part
longtime = Split(dbCellData, ChrW(32))(1) 'this gives the time part with milliseconds
dbtime = Split(longtime, ".")(0) 'this gives time without milliseconds but not rounded
```

Referral: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql